# How to slow down typewriter text animation?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, bootstrap-4, css-animations

I'm working on my portfolio and added a typewriter effect to the second line of text, but I feel like it's going too fast. I've tried tweaking animation seconds, delay, etc, but nothing is working. Here is the code:

Html

```
    <div class="banner">
  <div class="container h-100">
    <div class="row h-100 align-items-center">
      <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <h1 class="font-weight-light">Hi, I'm Kevin McCall</h1>
                      <!--Typewriter Animation Here-->
        <p class="font-weightlead">A Front-End Web Developer<span class="blinkcursor"> 
      _</span></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* Typewriter Effect */
.banner p {
color: red;
font-size: 50px;
margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow-wrap: break-word;
overflow: hidden;
max-width: 100%;
display: inline-block;
animation: typing 4s steps(60, end);
animation-delay: 2s;
 }

 /* Blinking Underscore */
.blinkcursor{
 animation: blink 1s infinite;
 color: white;
 }

/* Typing Animation */
@keyframes typing {
from {
    max-width: 0%;
}
to {
    max-width: 100%;
}
}

/* Blinking Underscore */
@keyframes blink{
to {opacity: 0;}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

[Check the syntax for using "animation" in CSS.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) There are multiple ways to make it work, such as:

```
animation: 10s steps(60, end) typing;
```

Where **10s** is the duration variable. Alternatively, you could use [animation-duration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-duration).

This has worked for me with your code in Chrome.

Comment: Thank you! I got it to work the way I wanted it to with your suggestion.

I just had one more question, if you wouldn't mind helping. I'm just trying to avoid making another post just for this.

How would I go about making the blinking cursor show up first before text, blinking for about 3 seconds, and then have typewriter animation start and then blink cursor at the end of the text once the animation is done.